# Walking Dead: Why wasn't the bazooka used at the end of season 6

Tags: the-walking-dead

During the final episode of Walking Dead season 6, Rick's party in the RV confronts numerous roadblocks set up by Negan's men, where the use of the bazooka would have been ideal, yet they never did. Why was this?

Comment: Because of noise? That's just a theory.

Comment: I agree with @JackBNimble. Any loud noise will attract huge hoards of zombies.

Comment: Agreed, but they weren't on foot and used it in a similar situation before

Comment: Did they have any more ammunition for it? So much as I know they haven't fired it again since the bikers on the road, at least not in the TV series. Not sure about the comics

Comment: @KaiQing Daryl fired it after the bikers in the road, he fired it into the pool at Alexandria after the walls collapsed. All the zombies were then attracted to it. That makes two shots, I'm sure when Abraham found it it had more than 2 rockets with it

Comment: for the record, this wasn't a Bazooka, but an RPG-7, most likely the "Amerikansky" derivative. Bazooka is a WWII-era weapon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Why would they have had it with them?

Rick's crew were just taking Maggie to Hilltop they were not expecting various blockades to be set up in front of them by a group they thought they had already dealt with, and had the upper hand over the small band of Saviours (they thought were left).

Why would they have brought a Bazooka with them on something they considered routine?

The greatest threat they were expecting to face would be zombies, which they would be able to deal with armed as they were.

They probably kept it safe at Alexandria for an unexpected emergency situation.

In hindsight the Bazooka would have been great to have with them, and maybe they should have turned around after the first or second blockade, but they were confident in their abilities and later on they were starting to panic. They may even have thought the way back was blockaded as well.

Answer (score 0):

Daryl shot **one** rocket at the bikers then **another** round was shot into the pond at Alexandria to start a fire for the walkers to walk into. When Abraham found the RPG, there was **one** rocket in it **plus** 3 more in the ammunition case, so they could've used it 4 times.

Sure, they weren’t planning on fighting, they were only going to Hilltop for Maggie, but they’d been running into multiple fights every time they were coming or going from Hilltop, so it wouldn’t be smart to not bring the RPG with them!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  While it is useful to establish that it they _could_ have used it, this doesn't really answer the question why they _didn't_.